# VB.net with access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a program that uses access database to store the information. The problem I am encountering is when I shared from my desktop and I go to another desktop it doesnt want to add a new record or the query that is appending the information is not working. It only works in the desktop that I ran the msi. Can anybody help me what I am doing wrong. I am not using remote desktop nor team viewer. I am not using remote services like remote desktop or team viewer. First thing I ran the msi and install the program in my desktop. Secondly I got to my c drive and share that forlder where the program lives. Third I go to another computer click on network and I look for my computer and go to that folder and run that application. Next I tried to test my program by adding a new record but it gives me a message there is no query to update this record. I go back to my desktop and it works find.

Comment: Please, edit and give more details how are you sharing your desktop: Remote Services? Remote Desktop? Team Viewer?.

Comment: I am not using remote services like remote desktop or team viewer. First thing I ran the msi and install the program in my desktop. Secondly I got to my c drive and share that forlder where the program lives. Third I go to another computer click on network and I look for my computer and go to that folder and run that application. Next I tried to test my program by adding a new record but it gives me a message there is no query to update this record. I go back to my desktop and it works find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the program is referencing to the location of the database on THAT pc you're running it to...
C:\ on your pc is not same C:\ on the other pc.

Comment: How Can I fix the problem. What setting do I have to change

Comment: Would it be a lot better to install it in the server

Comment: I found a solution for this problem temporaly is not the same how I expected but At least it work. What I did to kind of make it work like I wanted I did the following. When I Added a new data source I told visual studio not to make a copy into the project but before I added I left the database in some common place like the server that we are connected tried it out and it work.

Comment: But I was hoping a different way than my way probably it could of work if i just install the msi in the server and everyone gotten a shortcut dont know.

Comment: A server would be ideal, another possibility is that you can also backend your access database to a SQL server.

Comment: I never done sql it always intimidates me doing something i never done before especially when there is not a book or videos that I can follow everything I done for this program have been self taught by reading and asking questions online. By the way Hypenate is mysql and sql the samething